# How to use StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer with SignalR.Redis (2.2)

Tags: redis, signalr, stackexchange.redis, booksleeve

Currently SignalR.Redis is using Booksleeve.

However, SignalR.Redis has now migrated to StackExchange.Redis instead of Booksleave in the signalR.Redis (2.2 Dev Branch).

We can still specify a single Redis server using the same code after upgrading to 2.2:

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("localhost", 6379, string.Empty, "myApp");

However, I am now wondering how I can use the ConnectionMultiplexer (available in StackExchange.Redis) to specify multiple servers with SignalR.Redis (instead of specifying just one single server).

The answer here: [Using SignalR with Redis messagebus failover using BookSleeve's ConnectionUtils.Connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902572/using-signalr-with-redis-messagebus-failover-using-booksleeves-connectionutils/24386988#24386988) has taken me in the right direction, however I am confused as to how I implement it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: (From SE.redis author): I am not a signalr user: I don't have a clue. If you or someone figures out how to make such a plugin, I'm sure it would be welcomed.

Comment: Hi Marc, I guess it will be explained in the SignalR 2.2 examples once released. Thanks for responding to my request to checkout the question, appreciated. (and thank you for SE.Redis!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is not possible to specify a ConnectionMultiplex on SignalR 2.2.
I opened an issue about that here 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3383

and I'm creating a PR to the repo. Damian marked that issue for the milestone 2.2.1, hopefully will be released soon (of course I've to send the PR first)

.u